# UINavigationController not added correctly when initiated by viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, viewdidload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call function on "viewDidLoad" [SOLVED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221843/call-function-on-viewdidload-solved)

I have function, startApp, which looks like this:

```
- (void)startApp {
NSLog(@"startApp initiated");

aNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:aNavController animated:YES]; }
```

When called by a button, like:

```
- (IBAction)showSettings:(id)sender {
[self startApp]; }
```

It works fine, but called by viewDidLoad, like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self startApp]; }
```

"startApp initiated" is outputted but the NavigationController does not appear. I have no idea why this is, it seems to that they should work the same way? Being in the same file and all. Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working properly?

Thank you,
Tobias Tovedal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this method in viewdidLoad [self performSelector:@selector(loadView) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]; now create one method - (void) loadView { //write your navigation code here }

Comment: Brilliant! `[self performSelector:@selector(startApp) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];` in viewDidLoad solved it! Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad you are attempting to cover up an existing view with a navigation view.  That would work with most view controllers, but I think the UINavigationViewController wants to be the root or bottom-most view controller in your app.

Perhaps it would work to instantiate your navigation view controller, then create the view you want to appear within it.

It's tricky to use navigation controllers directly from code.  You'd have a much easier time if you used Xcode's File->New Project to create a Navigation-Based App, then added whatever existing code you have to that.

Comment: Okay, I think I get what your saying, but I fail to see why initiating startApp in viewDidLoad would be any different from initiating it through a button push. The idea is that you should directly be navigated to the app's settings view upon starting the app. This view should also be able to be reached through a button push, unfortunately I don't think creating this app with the Navigation-BasedApp template will create this effect.

Comment: Are you actually able to show a navigation controller by pushing a button in an existing app?

Comment: When viewDidLoad is called, the view that just loaded is not actually on screen yet.  It may be that trying to show a navigation controller on top of an incompletely-instantiated UIView just doesn't work.  Does it work if you call startApp instead from viewDidAppear?

Comment: Yes, it brings up a view with a navigation controller so it works. Adding `[self startApp];` like so: `- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self startApp];
}` does make the navigation controller view appear upon startup, but when i close the uinva-view it comes back, since that view then "appears" and viewDidAppear is called, tricky :P

Comment: So you might be correct in thinking that to "show a navigation controller on top of an incompletely-instantiated UIView just doesn't work", but I'd like to get to the bottom of this. I suppose adding some sort of counter to viewDidAppear so the function is only called once would solve the problem, but I hardly think that's the best way.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot present a view controller in viewDidLoad method. try it out in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Adding `[self startApp];` to `viewDidAppear` does initiate the functin correctly upon startup, however every time I go back to that view, the navigation controller pops up again.

Comment: then do as Don Quixote said.. create navigation based application.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option, my temporary solution will be to make some sort of value change from TRUE to FALSE when viewDidAppear is called, and only have startApp execute when that value is TRUE. It's not pretty but I guess it'll have to do.

Comment: I think you are trying to use the navigation controller in a way that it is not meant to be used.  Go have a look at the UINavigationController.h header file.  It is a tremendously complex class.  I'm pretty sure that the navigation controller has always been intended to be the root level view controller in an app, and that instantiating it on top of some other view controller that's not under the navigation controller's control has never been tested by Apple.  If it works, you'd be lucky.  It sounds like it doesn't work.  Anything you could do to get it to work would likely be an awful hack.

Comment: @DonQuixote - thank you for all your help, Droid's answer solved my problem though. I'm guessing the delay allows `viewDidLoad` to finish loading the root view, or something, I'm just guessing.